Keeping gradient fixed when rotating artwork - Illustrator CC
Just a question about using the transparency tool in Illustrator
I've been creating gradients to add shading but if I rotate the artwork the shading changes direction. Is there any work around to this that allows me to still keep it as a vector?
I've used the same technique as this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKo1Nr1QdM8


Gradients should remain relative to their parent object. i.e. rotate with the shape. How are you adding gradients, specifically?

@Scott https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKo1Nr1QdM8

oh.. not a simple answer. It's all dependent upon the location of the free form points.. operative word being "free". For the opacity masks, you need to ensure the mask is linked to the object. If it's linked to multiple objects, well that's another issue. That tutorial assumes the basic forms are set and not moving. All the texture is done by masking the primary shapes and changing blending modes. The texture isn't actually applied to the objects at all. I'm sure there's some way to build things more independently, but I don't have the time at the moment to sit through an entire 1hr tutorial.

I'l be honest, from what I saw, none of that construction would be my method. That doesn't mean it's "bad" or somehow "incorrect". It's just not how I would construct things. being a very long-term user, I learned Illustrator before any transparency was possible and tend to still kind of avoid most of it today. Using transparency and blend modes to allow something like a texture to "bleed" through a shape, is just not my preferred construction.

@Scott fair enough. So what would be an alternative? I like the stippling effect. Would photoshop be a better option? (that wouldn't be vector though_

While a bit verbose at times.. this video is more my methodology.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVwvw30LE2w the texture is all part of the shape, or relative to the shape via clipping masks, rather than being a background bleeding through.

That video uses Draw Inside - Draw Inside simply creates clipping masks, in case anyone is unaware.
